# Clarification about adjoint representation and Lie Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L = sl(2, F)$, and take the standard basis

$$x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad h = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

The multiplication table is $[xy] = h$, $[hx] = 2x$, $[hy] = -2y$.

So far so good, I understood why those are a basis and the multiplication table is correct. Not it says "notice that $x, y, h$ are eigenvectors for ad$(h)$, corresponding to eigenvalues $2, -2, 0$$...

And here I got stuck, because

- How can a matrix be an eigenvector? (**got it**)
- It says nothing on what ad$(h)$ is (only "adjoint representation") and I have no clue in how to "compute" it, if it's a thing one can do (?) (**solved this part on my own**)

Thank you for the help!

**EDITS**

I still don't get this part:

"Consider a generic element $ax + by + ch$; appling ad$(x)$ twice we get $-2bx$."

I tried to do the calculation, like using ad$(x) = 2x$ and applying it but I did not get that result.

Comment: do you know the definition of an eigenvector for a linear map?  If not, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#General_definition) will be helpful.  Once you have the definition you need to apply it in the special case of $\operatorname{ad}(h) : L \to L$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers I'm not getting how a matrix $x$ can be an eigenvector of a matrix of higher dimension. Also, later it says "let $ax + by + ch$ an element of $I$, ideal of $L$. **Applying ad$(x)$ twice** we get $-2bx$.
How is it possible to apply a $3\times 3$ matrix on a $2\times 2$ one??

Comment: OK, but I'm trying to tell you that you need to go and look up the definition of an eigenvector of a linear map so that you can understand this. Your comments about matrices are beside the point - a linear map is not a matrix.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Ok, let me see if I can get this: $x$ is an eigenvector of ad$(h)$ because the map $T(v)$ in this case is what I called below ad$(h, x)$, and since
$$ad(h, x) = 2x$$
I can say $x$ is eigenvector of ad$(h, x)$ with eigenvalue $2$. Is this right?

Comment: Almost, but your notation is wrong - you are mixing functions f and their outputs f(a). The map is ad(h). It's a map from L to L. It satisfies ad(h)(x) =2x so x is a 2-eigenvector for ad(h).

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes, I have to refine my notations because they could be wrong or unclear. Thank you for this! 
I still have a problem though in understanding how to apply ad$(x)$ twice to $ax + by + ch$ uhm

Comment: Why on earth does this have a downvote and a vote to close? Details and clarity, really?! How unabashedly obtuse... What details? What obscurity needs clarity? A vote that **literally** worsens things, quite a feat!

Answer (score 2):

> I still don't get this part:
>
> "Consider a generic element $ax + by + ch$; appling ad$(x)$ twice we get $-2bx$."
>
> I tried to do the calculation, like using ad$(x) = 2x$ and applying it but I did not get that result.

Because $ad(x) =2x$ is not true, or rather, makes no sense. I do admit the notation is unfortunate, and I forgive you your rude "shut up" because I do remember it confused me too at the beginning.

The **map** you want to apply is $ad(x)$. You still have to apply **that map**, to $x$, to $y$ and to $h$, respectively. I will highlight it in red and put brackets around it so you see it. We have (check this!)

$\color{red}{(ad(x))} (x) = 0$ and $\color{red}{(ad(x))} (y) = h$ and $\color{red}{(ad(x))} (h) = -2x$.

Now let's just call that red map $f$. If you have any linear map $\color{red}{f}$ such that

$\color{red}{f} (x) = 0$ and $\color{red}{f} (y) = h$ and $\color{red}{f} (h) = -2x$,

then what is

$\color{red}{f}(ax+by+ch) = ?$

And then, what do you get if you apply that map $\color{red}{f}$ to the result again ? I.e. what is

$\color{red}{f} ( \color{red}{f}(ax+by+ch)) = ??$

If you do not get $-2bx$ for ??, show me what you got for ?.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the structure equations of $sl(2, F)$:

$$[xy] = h \qquad [hx] = 2x \qquad [hy] = -2y$$

From here, let's say we search for ad$(x)$, then we have:

$$\text{ad}(x, x) = [xx] = 0$$
$$\text{ad}(x, y) = [xy] = h$$
$$\text{ad}(x, h) = [xh] = -2x$$

Which means

$$\text{ad}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

In a very similar way we find

$$\text{ad}(y) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and so on.

Comment: The space of matrices is a vector space.

Comment: $x,y,h$ are vectors of the $3$-dimensional $K$ vector space $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$. In fact, this vector space is a subspace of $K^4=\mathfrak{gl}_2(K)$ with basis $e_1=(1,0,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0,0),e_3=(0,0,1,0),e_4=(0,0,0,1)$. Then $x=e_2,y=e_3,h=e_1-e_4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, I misread! Why the downvote though?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didnot insult o.O

Comment: @DietrichBurde Anyway, thank you! I really did forgot that I can express a vector under the form of a matrix, to say it so (forgive the rough terminology).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry but I won't delete my answer just because of that. My answer DOES INDEED ANSWER to a part of the doubts I had at the beginning. I removed that part (I understood it, in the comments).